# complex Xcode project with multiple .xcconfig files and cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I am working on an iOS project where we are in the unfortunate situation that some of the libraries we must use comes in two versions. A version for debug, and a version for production.
It is not possible to debug with the production lib. and it is likewise not possible to use the debug lib. in production.

To solve this problem we have set up multiple targets (one for debugging and one for production) in the project. These targets use separate .xcconfig files (App-Debug.xcconfig and App-Production.xcconfig) to define the: LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS, HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS & OTHER_LDFLAGS for each target.

This all works just great, but it is becomming a pain to keep track of all our third party dependencies manually. 
Hence we decided to start using CocoaPods to manage some of our third party dependencies.

But the because of these "two version" libraries we can't use the Pods.xcconfig as intended, but need to append the settings from it to our own App-Debug.xcconfig and App-Production.xcconfig.

I am not sure of the right way to do this, as everything I try, seems to not compile because my pods can't be found.

Our Pods.xcconfig:

```
ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS = YES
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = ${PODS_HEADERS_SEARCH_PATHS}
LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = "$(PODS_ROOT)/TestFlightSDK"
OTHER_LDFLAGS = -ObjC -lTestFlight -lz -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit
PODS_BUILD_HEADERS_SEARCH_PATHS = "${PODS_ROOT}/BuildHeaders" "${PODS_ROOT}/BuildHeaders/AFNetworking" "${PODS_ROOT}/BuildHeaders/TestFlightSDK"
PODS_HEADERS_SEARCH_PATHS = ${PODS_PUBLIC_HEADERS_SEARCH_PATHS}
PODS_PUBLIC_HEADERS_SEARCH_PATHS = "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/AFNetworking" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/TestFlightSDK"
PODS_ROOT = ${SRCROOT}/Pods
```

App-Debug.xcconfig:

```
#include "Config-XXX.xcconfig"
#include "Config-Tesseract.xcconfig"
#include "Config-AppMeasurement.xcconfig"
#include "Config-Libxml2.xcconfig"
#include "Config-Frameworks.xcconfig"

LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) $(XXX_LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATH_DEBUG) $(TESSERACT_LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATH) $(APPMEASUREMENT_LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATH)

HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) $(TESSERACT_HEADER_SEARCH_PATH) $(LIBXML2_HEADER_SEARCH_PATH) $(XXX_HEADER_SEARCH_PATH)

OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -lz -lxml2 -lstdc++ -all_load -ObjC -lXXXLibrary $(APPLE_FRAMEWORKS)
```

App-Production.xcconfig:

```
#include "Config-XXX.xcconfig"
#include "Config-Tesseract.xcconfig"
#include "Config-AppMeasurement.xcconfig"
#include "Config-Libxml2.xcconfig"
#include "Config-Frameworks.xcconfig"

LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) $(XXX_LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATH_PRODUCTION) $(TESSERACT_LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATH) $(APPMEASUREMENT_LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATH)

HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) $(TESSERACT_HEADER_SEARCH_PATH) $(LIBXML2_HEADER_SEARCH_PATH) $(XXX_HEADER_SEARCH_PATH)

OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -lz -lxml2 -lstdc++ -all_load -ObjC -lXXXLibrary $(APPLE_FRAMEWORKS)
```

Config-XXX.xcconfig:

```
XXX_LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATH_DEBUG = "$(SRCROOT)/External/XXX"
XXX_LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATH_PRODUCTION = "$(SRCROOT)/External/XXX/LibProd"

XXX_HEADER_SEARCH_PATH = "$(SRCROOT)/External/XXX/headers"
```

As we can see both the Pods.xcconfig and our own App-Debug.xcconfig sets the: LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS, HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS & OTHER_LDFLAGS.

What I need is to have the values declared in Pods.xcconfig appended to the values we declare in App-Debug.xcconfig.

We are using Xcode 4.6 and building for iOS 4.3.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your podfile can support this. You should end up with something like this

```
platform :ios, "5.0"
link_with ['App', 'App-Debug'] 

pod 'Shared-Pod'

target :App, :exclusive => true do
  pod 'Normal-Pod'
end

target :App-Debug, :exclusive => true do
  pod 'Debug-Pod'
end
```

This will generate two xcconfig files, one for each target.

Comment: This is really awesome, I had no idea this was possible.

I will give this a try, over the next few days - We have no setup to handle custom pods (yet).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using two targets, try defining different values for `XXX_LIBRARY_PATH` in the *configuration* (easiest in the GUI, sadly). If you only have two configurations and they are named appropriately, you can even do something like `XXX_LIBRARY_PATH = FooPath/$(CONFIGURATION)`.

It is not possible for one target config to append properties to another; the "inheritance" is strictly SDK → Project[Config] → Target[Config].

Comment: The way we have solved this now (without using cocoapods) is by defining two search paths for the XXXLibrary. 

I edited my post with the contents of Config-XXX.xcconfig

However that is not the problem, the problem comes in to effect when we try to move some of our third party dependencies to cocoapods. Then the dependencies we move can not be found by Xcode, and the project won't build.